# git stash but keep whats being stash instead of reverting to last commited change

Tags: git, git-stash

So when I `git stash` it will pack my changes since the last commit to a list, however is their any way that I do not have to commit, but still stash and keep the uncommitted changes or of their is any other git command for that ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. `stash` [takes the dirty state of your working directory — that is, your modified tracked files and staged changes — and saves it on a stack of unfinished changes that you can reapply at any time.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)

Comment: Dont forget that you can name your stash to retrieve it more easily later with `git stash save "thenameyouwant"` . Then you can list all your stashes with `git stash list` (it will display the name if you've given one).. then you can `git stash apply` the stash you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You with a single command you can't. 
But you can stash the changes and then apply they back, keeping them into the stash. Check the [stash docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) for more info.

```
git stash
git stash apply
```

If you want, you can create a alias in your .gitconfig file. You can check how to create alias [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).

```
[alias]
stash-save = !git stash && git stash apply
```

Comment: in the alias is it possible to pass optional flag that should do `stash list` too ?

Comment: just put another command like : stash-save = !git stash && git stash apply && git stash list

Comment: if you wan't to be a option, the you must create a script, but then create a stash-save.sh script and put it on your path

Answer (score 0):

If you have changes that you would like to keep around but not have to keep in your stash stack perhaps you could store them on a separate topic branch.

So, the procedure would be:

```
# do some work
# realize you want to go in another direction but keep your changes somewhere
git checkout -b topicName
git add .
git commit -m "useful description"
git checkout - # go back to previous branch
```

Then, whenever you want you can either merge or cherry-pick the "stashed" away changes on that topic branch back on to the branch you are working on.

```
git merge topicName
```

Comment: Typically the reason to want a diff to hang around as a stash and not as a commit is because it's required to temporarily integrate or exercise a feature while awaiting a team member to finish some concurrent work. You want it as a stash because you might want to switch branches here and there; you don't want it on a branch because you're working on a branch already. And you don't want the changes in the history because they're ephemeral and designed to be thrown away.